# Getting Variable Undefined on the first http get request

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-http

I want to pass the query string api_toke={{tokenStored}} with every request. The below code is what I've used to achieve it. Problem is that the token is undefined when the page gets called initially but after that it is working as expected. How do I solve this?

This is the error thrown in the console

```
polyfills.js:3 GET http://myapp.dev/app/public/api/project?api_token=undefined 401 (Unauthorized)

list-projects.ts:39 Response {_body: "{"error":"Unauthenticated."}", status: 401, ok: false, statusText: "Unauthorized", headers: Headers…} "Error Caught
```

Component

```
export class ListProjectsPage {

   ionViewDidLoad() {
      this.http.get(this.config.url.api+this.config.endpoint.listprojects)
        .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.projects = data.json();
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error,"Error");
      });
  }

}
```

My Custom HTTP Provider

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import * as AppConfig from '../../app/app.config';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class HttpProvider {

  config: any;
  token: any;
  constructor(public http: Http,public storage: Storage) {
    this.config = AppConfig.config;
    this.storage.get('token').then(token => {
      this.token = token;
    }).catch(e => {
      this.token = null;
    });
  }

  get(url:string){
    return this.http.get(url+'?api_token='+this.token);
  }

}
```

Comment: wont a simple if else block solve the issue ? in the get like `if (this.token) do this else return observable false`

Comment: don't understand. Please explain

Comment: @JSnow, did you try my solution?

Comment: yes, didn't work. the get event is not getting fired

Comment: Did you solve it? if not i have updated my answer, although previous once was better.

Answer (score 0):

what i can suggest to you is :

1- be sure the token is in the localstorage and the key is `'token'` :-)

2 - maybe use a plug in for Angular2/4 and Ionic 2/3 app to do the quivalent of Angularjs and Ionic 1 http interceptor .. i can suggest to youthis one (i use this) : `angular2-http-interceptor` (`https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-http-interceptor`)

then you can do something like this:

a) create a model for you token response from the back end like:

```
export class Auth {
    public access_token: string;
    public userName: string;

}
```

b) create a service (with NO @inject() decoration) like:

```
import { Request, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { IHttpInterceptor } from 'angular2-http-interceptor';
import { Auth } from '../models/index';


export class AuthInterceptor implements IHttpInterceptor {
    constructor() {

    }

    before(request: Request): Request {
        if (localStorage && localStorage.length > 0 && localStorage.getItem("AuthData")) {

            var auth = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")) as Auth;
            if (!auth || !auth.access_token) return request;

            request.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth.access_token)
        }
        return request;
    }


}
```

c) the in your app.module use like this:

```
 HttpInterceptorModule.withInterceptors([{
            deps: [],
            provide: HttpInterceptor,
            useClass: AuthInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }])
```

NOW every time you do a http request it automatically check if you have the token and inject it in the header of your request .. hope it helps you! ...

N.B if you need to change the way as you pass the token (maybe in querystring and not in the header of the request) you can change the B) point and it's reflected for ALL your request

Comment: Hey federico,
I've checked the key. The token key is correct. it is working as expected on every other request except the first one.

Comment: mmm maybe try to do a JSON.PARSE before use it so for example...this.storage.get('token').then(token => {
      this.token = JSON.parse( token);
    }).catch(e => {
      this.token = null;
    });

Comment: and are you sure you've to pass it in QUERYSTRING and not in the HEADERS?

Answer (score 0):

It is `undefined` because `get` method is getting called before `storage` can resolve promise and assign value to `token.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import * as AppConfig from '../../app/app.config';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class HttpProvider {

  config: any;
  token: any;
  constructor(public http: Http,public storage: Storage) {
    this.config = AppConfig.config; 
  }

  get(url:string){
    this.storage.get('token').then(token => {
       return this.http.get(url+'?api_token='+this.token);
    })
  }
}
```

Although this will also work but its better to store token in provider (`config` in your case) at the launch of application, and use already defined token while making `http` calls.